# What is Cross-Platform Development?

Tags: .net, mono, cross-platform

.NET is for Windows !

But, though for linux environment, MONO achieves goal for .NET support. What is Mono ? Is it linux IDE for dotnet support ? How many languages are supported by .NET ?

Mono uses cross-platform development concept. What does it mean by ?

Comment: Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429451/is-developing-in-mono-cross-platform/3429493#3429493) I posted previously about maintaining compatibility with cross platform between .NET and Mono.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is a cross-platform implementation of the [Common Language Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) as well as much of the .NET Framework.  It will allow code developed for .NET to be used on other platforms, including Linux.

There is an IDE associated with it ([MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)), but that is a separate project.

> How many languages are supported by .NET ?

There are many [.NET languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_languages), though C# and VB.NET are the most common.

Comment: Are there any more other than F# and J# (which AFAIK doesn't exist anymore)?

Comment: @Oren A: Yes, though most others are non-Microsoft.  For example, Delphi Prism is very robust: http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism

Answer (score 4):

Cross-platform generally refers to a technology which can be used for multiple operating systems. For example, Mono is an open-source implementation of the Common Language Runtime (CLR), which are the underlying libraries required by .NET.

Mono runs on Linux, BSD, Unix, Mac OS X, Solaris and Windows. Mono itself is not an IDE, but several cross-platform IDEs exist as well. The most popular is [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).

Several languages are built on top of the .NET framework such as C# and VB.NET. C# is the most popular for cross-platform development.

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find more information on cross plattform development in general.: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform

Basically it's developing a application for different plattforms(e.g. Windows, Mac)

Mono is a cross-platform library which implents the .NET framework on Linux.

You can find a lot of information about Mono here:
http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

And there is also a IDE (MonoDevelop) for Mono:
http://monodevelop.com/

You also ask what languages are supported by .NET. You can find a list here:
http://www.startvbdotnet.com/dotnet/languages.aspx

The most important are C++, C#, F# and VB.NET

Answer (score 2):

Cross-platform development refers to the development of software to run on a machine substantially different from the one used by the developer.  For example, there are many useful programs which run on processors with 128 bytes of RAM or less and 4K of ROM or less; for example, the PIC popular 16C54 microcontroller, which includes offers 25 bytes of RAM and 768 bytes of ROM, is used in many small gizmos like remote controls, appliance timers, etc.  It would be pretty much impossible to edit the code for a 16C54 on a 16C54, so instead a programmer (human) will develop the code on something like a PC and use a device called a programmer to copy the code into the microcontroller chip.

Multi-platform development refers to the development of software to run on a variety of different machines.  This obviously contains a substantial element of cross-platform development (since the developer's machine will likely only match one of the machines for which the software is written) but a lot of cross-platform development is targeted toward a one particular machine and is thus not multi-platform development.

Answer (score 1):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is an implementation of the [Common Language Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) and some parts of the [.NET Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) that runs on Linux, BSD, MacOSX, Windows amongst others ([Here](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) you can see the supported platforms). The idea is to allow code developed for .NET to be used on as many platforms as possible.

Mono is not an IDE, but there is an IDE that runs on Mono, the IDE itself it’s called [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/).

Cross-platform means that you can compile once and run it in multiple platforms, in this case, compile once and run in every platform supported by Mono.

.NET supports [many different languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages) (C#, C++, VB.NET, Fortran, Perl, Python amongst others), but the most common ones are C# an VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) with support for Mac, Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-platform means that you can build an app (or separate apps) for multiple OS platforms from a single code base. In addition to the other tools mentioned here, [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com) is also a great option. It builds native apps using native controls for Windows, Mac OS and Linux from a single code base (you can even share the UI, which is not something other tools often let you do).