# Can a C# program be cross-platform?

Tags: c#, cross-platform

I'm a newbie to programming, and I'm considering using C# to write a VERY simple program that simply edits a text file.

- Will it work on Macs and Linux? What will work?
- I want to know what makes a program cross-platform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is developing in Mono cross-platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429451/is-developing-in-mono-cross-platform)

Comment: @TrueWill Why was this question closed as "off topic"?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I don't remember. I might have picked a different reason; I'm not sure if it's "last closer wins" or "majority" for reason. IMHO it's WAY too broad as worded. I liked Justin's answer, though. Feel free to vote to reopen and/or edit!

Comment: The CoreCLR repo contains the complete runtime implementation for .NET Core. see my answer below for details.

Comment: For a newbie, using C# to make a cross-platform GUI app is not straightforward. Better to try something more suited to the task such as Xojo. http://www.xojo.com

Comment: Is  visual studio (not vs code) available for linux and mac?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

C# can be compiled for and ran on multiple platforms (Windows, Linux, macOS) by using [.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/).

Previously, cross-platform development using C# could only be done by using [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) which is a third-party implementation however it is now recommended to use .NET Core as it is developed by Microsoft.

Comment: Sometimes Mono is ahead of the MS.NET runtime; it really depends on the feature.  For example, beta versions of Mono had support for C# 4's `dynamic` keyword long before Microsoft released an RC of .NET 4.

Comment: GREAT! It's funny to even think that I'd ever have a problem like this with what I intend to use it for. For now...

Comment: .net core is fully cross platform. Please update this answer with .net core as Google search leads to this answer for "is c# cross-platform"

Answer (score 14):

Now C# is fully cross platform and has variety of frameworks and run times.

Java is a language + framework. But C# is just a modern language. C# language features are very powerful, easy to learn. No confusion between framework and language.

C# can be used in following frameworks

- .Net core (Multi platform supports Linux, Windows and Mac), mostly used to develop restful services, web applications and enterprise systems
- .Net Framework (Windows only), Same as .net core, but has more windows only features
- Unity - One of most used game engine to develop games for PC, Sony, Xbox devices etc..
- Xamarin - To develop native Mobile apps (Android, IOS, Mac)
- .Net standard - Create a library in .net standard use in all above applications

**Java** - Code once, Ship same file to all platforms

**C++, C, Rust** - Code once, Compile for specific platform

**C#** - It is just a language, pick your framework according to requirement.

Most popular applications like Chrome, Firefox uses C++, Rust and they are compiled for each platform. But still they share the majority of code between these platforms. Some games use C++ to share the code between IOS and Android.

For new developers its good to start with NodeJS and C#. Both are easy and can do any type of applications.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all frameworks support all C# language features, such as the `dynamic` keyword.

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to answer something like that to somebody, which states that he just starts programming, but I'll try to give you an (somewhat simplified) overview: C# is a language, which is compiled into an executable program. The language itself is portable between plattforms, as long as you have a compiler on each target plattform. On Windows you have the "default" .Net implementation and on Linux/Mac you have Mono. To do something useful - like editing files - you have to use some libraries. There is a standard library which is available on each plattform. As long as you use only that functionality, your program will be cross plattform. Obviously is will not be cross plattform, as soon as you use some library specific to a certain plattform. Editing files is part of the standard library, so you can implement such simple tools in a cross plattform way. When choosing a book, you should look for books which focus on the "raw" language and not on Visual Studio or other specific tools.

Comment: "as long as you have a compiler on each target plattform" -- this is not completely true.  Output from the Microsoft compiler can be run on Mono, and output from the Mono compiler can be run on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

A new open source release from Microsoft called CoreCLR is cross-platform and can now be used for this

> The CoreCLR repo contains the complete runtime implementation for .NET Core. It includes RyuJIT, the .NET GC, native interop and many other components. It is cross-platform, with multiple OS and CPU ports in progress.
>    -[from the CoreCLR repo](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr)

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend c# as the top choice for multiplatform coding. I would recommend python instead it is very easy to run even as a script and works perfectly on all platforms. If you insist on c# be prepared to deal with the same problem explained by Justin Ethier. Python on the other hand, is the same for all platforms, it is super powerful fast and even has wrappers ready to connect to other languages.

Answer (score 2):

C# is cross-platform thanks to .NET Core, but without a cross-platform User Interface library you can only make very basic console programs with it. In order to make cross-platform apps for Windows, Mac and Linux you need a cross-platform User Interface library like [Nevron Open Vision](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, C# is fully cross-platform thanks to .NET Core.
.NET Core is a free and open-source, managed computer software framework for Windows, Linux, and macOS operating systems. It is the cross-platform successor to the .NET Framework which only run on Windows. The project is primarily developed and supported by Microsoft (through the .NET Foundation).

Answer (score 0):

C# is cross platform and you can run your program in Windows/Linux and Mac. For Linux, though, you need to run it [using mono](http://go-mono.com)

Comment: C# is just a language. The Visual C# compiler and the .NET CLR are not cross-platform.

Comment: @BoltClock Correct, what I meant to say is that you can write code in C#, compile it and run it on any platform (or virtually all, that might be a broad statement). The IL code produced can be run in Linux (using Mono) or in Windows/Mac using the .NET Framework runtime environment. As cdhowie points out, you can compile it using MS c# Compiler and run it in Linux using mono w/o recompilation. I have an asp.net app (old, 1.1 Framework) that I built in Windows and run in Linux using mod_mono for Apache.