# How to execute a C# code in python?

Tags: c#, python, cross-platform

C# is known to be a cross-platform programming language, just like python.

Since C # is much more efficient than Python, it would be interesting to use C# to do the calculations that need efficiency and so, to import the results in python.

I know it is possible to do this in c, but in that case I would have to compile the c module on different platforms (linux, windows and mac) :(

Could someone direct me where I can find related information???

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975207/can-a-c-sharp-program-be-cross-platform

Comment: "Since C # is much more efficient than Python, ..." (citation needed) -- did you actually test this or do you just assume it?

Comment: I affirm this from my own experience. Each number or letter in python is transformed into an object and used as a pointer. C# works with these values directly.

Comment: pythonnet is interop library between C# and CPython that works cross-platform