# Using Unity in Ubuntu but building for Windows Platform

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

This may be a noob question, but bear with me since I'm very new to this whole video game dev thingy. Suppose I wanted to use Ubuntu as my main distro on my laptop (Dell XPS 9575) and decided to develop a small indie game using Unity3D, but I'd want to release it on Steam for Windows computers. Could I do all the programming in C# on Unity using Ubuntu as my main distro and then build it for Windows on a virtual machine? Or would using Ubuntu automatically exempt me from that?

Comment: Simply from a Win/Linux perspective - a dual boot might be beneficial for testing the app for Win.  An advantage of dual vs. VM, is memory allocation isn’t an issue with dual. If there is a central git repo, then pushing the project back and forth won’t be an issue.

Comment: @S3DEV, does this mean the programming is independent of testing the app on a different platform? Assuming I have the code in a git repo.

Comment: My C# days are long ago mate, sorry.  [Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6975207/6340496) and see if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Unity [supports Ubuntu](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/GettingStartedInstallingHub.html#:%7E:text=Unity%20officially%20supports,Ubuntu%2018.04:%7E:text=Unity%20officially%20supports%20the%20following%20Linux%20distributions%3A) and it's very easy to [build targeting windows](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html) when you have made your game